# How to write a test for a network listener?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, network-programming

I am currently writing a piece of C++ code that will listen for network connections. I'm using gtest to write unit tests but I've reached a problem I don't know how to fix:

How can I test the functions that listen for network connections? If I put this in my unit test they'll block.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might use gMock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use py.test to run my functional tests, even though this is a C++ project.